# App profile page showing wrong posts

Tags: bug, android-app, network-profile

I glanced at my profile this morning, and saw this:

[image: Profile screenshot]

The weird thing is, the post it shows under "Stack Overflow" (regarding the "partial" tag) is a *Meta* post, not a post on the main site.

I have a fair number of questions on the main site that have more upvotes, so I'd expect them to show. I also have more than 1 meta post, and it's not displaying them either.

This persists even after forcefully killing the app, and this morning was the first time I've ever seen it.

Not a bug deal, just a bug I noticed.

Android 6.0.1
App Version 1.0.89

Comment: I restarted my phone and it was fixed. Should I remove this?

Comment: Well, in the app everything is cached, sometimes for days.

Comment: @Carcigenicate nope. Don't remove it. I have a similar problem that fixes itself and later reappears. ["Profile on Android app lists meta posts instead of main"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290807/309993)