# Profile on Android app lists meta posts instead of main

Tags: discussion, bug, profile-page, android-app

> [image: screenshot of android app]

OnePlus One, latest COS13 non-root, stock OS. Stack Exchange android app version 1.0.89 (Play Store)

On my profile, I'm seeing my meta.ELU posts listed, instead of the main ELU ones. This happened several times over the last year or so, over different versions of the app.

Restarting app, or phone, changes nothing. Fixes itself usually, I think, sometime later by some reason unknown to me.

Just thought I should post it here, at least now.

Comment: How did you select your profile?

Comment: @PatrickHofman I opened the burger menu(?) on the left, and clicked on my username 'NVZ' on it.

Comment: From which site or panel?

Comment: @PatrickHofman from the app's home page "feed".

Comment: You happened to have opened a meta post from the app lately?

Comment: @PatrickHofman I am active on meta ELU, yes. But this happens even when I've not visited meta for a while.

Comment: And what if you open the main site from the app and open your profile then?

Comment: @PatrickHofman I don't know for sure. To me it appears random, irrespective of my currently active page. Btw, I can't reproduce the issue now no matter what I try.

Comment: @PatrickHofman now I see my normal profile, with a list of main-site posts. Don't know how it resolves automatically. https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgcaE.jpg

Comment: I guess there is a 'smart' site selector which tries to remember which site you were last active on.

Comment: @PatrickHofman in that case, I think that 'smart' site selector has some sort of bug. Because this happens even when I've not visited meta for days or weeks.

Comment: You know it also lists posts from other sites sometimes.